# How to convert user inputted (string) function into a math module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Further to my previously question that has helpfully answered, a new related question is:

How can I 'append' a user inputted transcendental function onto a math. prefix (math.*user_fn*) that python can than work with in the usual manner? Sorry being  beginner, I'm not sure of the precise terminology I shot be using, but I think I'm asking how to change object type in this case? 
e.g.

```
v1 = input("Type a transcendental function e.g. 'sin' or 'exp': ")
```

so that I can then compute something like:

```
math.v1(2.3)
```

Comment: The accepted answer uses getattr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in the usual way (i.e dot access). You can get it and call it on the spot with `getattr`. The fact is that `math.v1` will perform a `__getattribute__` call on the module object and look for an attribute who's name isn't the value of `v1` but, rather, the string `'v1'` itself.

That fails and there's no means to change it.

You should just opt for `getattr`, this supports dynamic attribute fetching:

```
getattr(math, v1)(2.3)
```

this attempts to grab an attribute whos' name equals the value of `v1` and then calls it on the spot. It's a shorter version for:

```
func = getattr(math, v1)
func(2.3)
```